# UI Layout while using Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a django form . Like as follows

```
class AForm(form.Form):
              first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
              last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

And I do have the html code like

```
<form action="zzzzzz" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want first name and last name next to each other .

Is it possible to do UI layout inside django form , itself, rather than at html page ?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize form layout by overriding `as_p` / `as_table` methods. For example:

```
class AForm(form.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def as_p(self):
        return render_to_string('forms/AForm.html', dict(form=self))
```

Where `forms/AForm.html` is a valid Django Template